# I'm encountering a Python error when I mix threading, input, and TCP sockets

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, input, runtime-error

I'm creating a program that uses threads to handle sockets and input at the same time. I've narrowed down the errors I'm getting to be replicable in these couple dozen lines of code. What happens to anyone else who runs the code below? I encounter a hang-up in waiting for the recv in the client. If I further try to send() more data in the server, I get a Broken Pipe error. And, even more weirdly, if I comment out the line that calls input(), the sockets work just fine.

What kind of weird interaction is going on between input(), sockets, and threading? And does anyone have a solution to this? Here's some code that generates the error.

Server:

```
import socket
import threading

def handle_connection(conn, addr):
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    message = data.decode('ascii').split()

    s = "TEST"
    conn.send(bytes(s, 'ascii')) #
    
    conn.close()    

def handle_input():
    while True:
       s = input()
       print(s)
        
HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 2000  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT));  #Empty first string = INADDR_ANY
    s.listen();
    
    w = threading.Thread(target=handle_input)
    w.start()

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        x = threading.Thread(target=handle_connection, args=(conn, addr))
        x.start()

    s.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 2000  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    message = "find_successor a"
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(bytes(message, 'ascii'))
    data = s.recv(1024)

print(f"Received {data!r}")
```

I appreciate any help or insight!

Comment: With an error at the client, I suspect that the server is closing its connection too soon. As an experiment try commenting out the `conn.close()` in the server.

Comment: This does not change anything, unfortunately. Same problem. :(

Comment: The code as shown works for me as I would expect with Python 3.8 on Linux, i.e. input thread is independent from the socket server thread and the client can send data and receive the response even while the server is also waiting for input().